# Value of uninitialized persistent variable in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

If I declare a variable as 'persistent' in MATLAB, how can I check if it has been initialized or not?

The exist() function apparently doesn't work (as the variable is treated as in existence as soon as I declare it to be persistent).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

isempty() was the function I was looking for. Teaches me to look at the example code from the documentation.

Comment: As a note: you can also use this to check if some global variables are initialized.